# Cant add class or interface in project. VS 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

In asp.net core, the project at some point lost the ability to add classes or something else to the project or any of its folders, writes - "please choose a project type". In other projects, such an opportunity is remained.
I have a last ver. VS 2019 on this moment.

The output of `dotnet --list-sdks` is :

```
2.1.507 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
2.2.105 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
3.1.100-preview1-014459 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

The ASP.NET Core project targets 3.0 :

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: Is the project targeting a .NET Core version that was removed perhaps? What is the `TargetFramework` in your csproj and what does `dotnet --list-sdks` show?

Comment: Which Visual Studio version do you have? 16.4 preview 2 has a bug that removes .NET Core 3.0 when installing 3.1 preview.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
2.1.507 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.105 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.100-preview1-014459 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
Now I have a last version VS 2019. In this moment i trying repair a VS :(

Comment: Post the information in the question itself. But `3.1.100-preview1-014459` *is* the 3.1 Preview. What does `TargetFramework` in your csproj look like? If the VS Preview removed 3.0, the solution is to download and install the 3.0 SDK again. Repairing VS will run the same setup procedure that removed the .NET Core 3 SDK

Comment: `TargetFramework`
netcoreapp3.0

Comment: Try installing the 3.0 SDK manually then. This is a know problem 16.4 Preview 2 can unistall 3.0. It doesn't always happen - I didn't have this problem for example. On the other hand, I probably installed SDK 3.1 manually before the preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3.1.100-preview1-014459` is the preview of .NET Core 3.1 SDK, installed with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 Preview 2. The strange thing is that the *3.0 SDK* is missing. Unless you created the ASP.NET Core project in the last 9 days, I suspect it uses the 3.0 SDK.

There's a known issue with 16.4 Preview 2  which removes the 3.0 SDK when installing 3.1. The solution is to [download and install 3.0 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) again. From [Announcing .NET Core 3.1 Preview 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1-preview-1/)

> **Known Issue:** The Visual Studio 16.4 installer may uninstall the .NET Core 3.0 Runtime when it installs .NET Core 3.1. We recommend you re-in-install or repair the .NET Core 3.0 SDK in that case.

Comment: Repairing is helped. Project used `TargetFramework` netcoreapp 3.0. Strange that he is missing in system. Thank you for help, bro!